# Is there any way to typeset my Beamer presentations on my iPad?

Tags: beamer, ipad

I'm considering buying one of the available LaTeX apps for my iPad. Among other things, one of the main things I'm interested in is tweaking my `beamer` presentations (particularly handy when on the go).

Does anyone if there's an app that can compile `beamer` locally, i.e. without connecting to some server as is the case for some? I'm not always guaranteed an Internet connection when traveling/commuting.

Comment: see http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/i-tex-therefore-ipad-reloaded/

Comment: As yet, I'd have to say "No".  TeX Writer doesn't have the graphic capabilities to cope with the PGF parts of `beamer`, TeXPad doesn't have the memory capacity.  Both are still in their infancy, though, and both developers are working on extending them so this will most likely soon change.

Answer (score 8):

Texpad developers here.

We added support for Beamer and Tikz in v1.5.0 and now the majority of beamer presentations and tikz diagrams typeset with Texpad on iOS. @AndrewStacey is correct that Texpad's internal TeX will occasionally run out of memory when typesetting large presentations, but we are working on this, and we expect it to be fixed in one of the early 1.5.x updates.

Comment: Any update two years later?